# how to set x-client-cert header in tcserver or F5?

Tags: tcserver, big-ip

Each request from the client must have the certificate in the header for it to successfully access the web service. The web service looks for it under the header name  x-client-cert. Can someone guide me on how one can set x-client-cert header with x509cert using F5 or tcserver 2.9.9?

Answer (score 0):

[This entry](https://devcentral.f5.com/codeshare?sid=584) on the DevCentral codeshare is the iRule you are looking for. You can exchange the SSLClientCertb64 header (line 42) with your x-client-cert header. If you don't need to pass the cert validity or the serial number, you can clean up the information stored in the memory for those and eliminate the headers being created for them.